# Is there any way to swap two characters in a string easily?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, swap

for example
input:

```
text = 'wish you “happy” every (day)'
```

expected output:

```
text = 'wish you (happy) every “day”'
```

I'd like to swap parentheses with quotations everywhere in an unknown text. 
I'm doing a school assignment and I'm NOT allowed to use list!!!
As strings are immutable so I'm not sure what to do then. please help！

Comment: Strings are immutable, but variables are not. You can still re-assign a different string to the same the variable (`text`).

Comment: Could you please share your attempts so far? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a silly answer using string.replace():

```
text = 'wish you “happy” every (day)'

text = text\
    .replace('”', '*')\
    .replace('“', "^")\
    .replace("(", '“')\
    .replace(")", '”')\
    .replace("*", ')')\
    .replace("^", '(')
```

## Here's a serious answer:

Since you have a list of characters to replace, build a dictionary of what character should be swapped with another character, then iterate through the string and create a new string which contains the original string with replaced letters. This way, you can have as many or as few strings in the switch dictionary as you want, and it will work without modification. Factored up to a larger scale, you might want to do something like store this dictionary elsewhere, for example if you're creating it based on user input that you get from an interface or a webapp. It's often good to separate the specification what you are doing from how you are doing it, because one can be treated as data (which characters to swap) whereas the other is logic (actually swapping them).

```
text = 'wish you “happy” every (day)'

newtext = ''
switch = {
    '“': '(', 
    '”': ')',
    '(': '“', 
    ')': '”',
}

for letter in text:
    if letter in switch: letter = switch[letter]
    newtext += letter
```

The reason I took an iterative approach is because we are swapping characters, so if you replace all instances of each character at the same time, characters will get swapped back once you swap the next one unless you include an intermediate step such as `*` in my silly answer or `###` in the other answer, which opens the possibility of collisions (if your text already contained `###` or `*` it would incorrectly be replaced).

immutability of strings is why you have to create the `newtext` string instead of replacing the characters in the original string as I iterate.

Comment: No answer is silly! this works well. Thanks! I'm just trying to find a better way.

Comment: @happier one second, I'm still typing!

Comment: yea I did. but I'm new here and this is my first question posed ever....I can't upvote with less than 15 reputations. I'm sorry

Comment: ha, yeah "new one"

Answer (score 3):

An intermediate replace is usually vulnerable, as text could contain the intermediate representation: `###...###` in Roopak A Nelliat's answer, `*` and `^` in Ryan's "silly" one (EDIT: as noted in Ryan's more serious text below).

Here's a regex solution without going through the intermediate replace:

```
text = 'wish you "happy" every (day)'
def replacer(match):
    quote, content = match.groups()
    if quote:
        return f'({content})'
    else:
        return f'"{content}"'
re.sub(r'(?:(")|\()(.*?)(?(1)"|\))', replacer, text)
# => 'wish you (happy) every "day"'
```

The regexp will match a starting delimiter (either `"` or `(`), then content, and a matching final delimiter (i.e. if the starting delimiter was `"` then `"`, if not then `)`). Then the replacer function constructs a replacement with the other set of delimiters.

Comment: This is cool because you're actually using the semantic structure of open and closing delimiters, but could this approach be simplified by using the separate open quote and close quote chars like in the original question? or would it be roughly the same?

Comment: @Ryan Oh, didn't notice OP wasn't using the normal double-quotes. Yes, it would be the equivalent: `r'(?:(“)|\()(.*?)(?(1)”|\))'` — you'd still want to pick the appropriate closing delimiter for each opening delimiter.

Comment: we haven't reached there so far, this is advanced for me, but thank you still!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you need would be regex replace. Also, the group should be retained.

*NOTE*: I had to use 3 replaces because there is a swap.

```
a = 'wish you "happy" every (day)'
b = re.sub(r'"(\w+)"', r'###\1###', a) 
// replaces words inside double quotes to words inside ###
// b = 'wish you ###happy### every (day)'

c = re.sub(r'\((\w+)\)', r'"\1"', b)
// replaces words inside paranthesis to words inside double quotes
// c = 'wish you ###happy### every "day"'

d = re.sub(r'###(\w+)###', r'(\1)', c)
// replaces the words inside ### to paranthesis
// d = 'wish you (happy) every "day"'
```